# How to identify individual controls within a search result using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a list of search results in the following link and would like to know on how can I identify the individual controls using dynamic xpath

http://www.bigbasket.com/cl/fruits-vegetables/?nc=nb

I'm able to get the list of product names displayed using the below line

```
List<WebElement> productResults = browser.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'product')]/div[2]/span[2]/a"));
```

I'm able to print the product names displayed in Page 1 using the below code, but however the list size is not matching with the list of results displayed in Page 1 so which I see blank lines in between when printing

```
System.out.println(productResults.size());
for(int i=0;i<productResults.size();i++){
        System.out.println(productResults.get(i).getText());
}
```

Also I tried to locate the individual controls such as Qty text box, Add button in a similar like how I located the product names but the list count is not matching so which I cannot specify the quantity, add the required product to the cart.

Could you please help me with this one?

Answer (score 1):

The first step is get only the visible itens (that is displayed), sou you can use this xpath:

```
"//*[contains(@id,'product')][not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]/div[2]/span[2]/a"
```

Now, you need to return the main iten div, that allows you to acess other functions. You can get the tag parents in this way:

```
"//*[contains(@id,'product')][not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]/div[2]/span[2]/a/../../.."
```

The elements that you recieve in this last XPath have all html itens that you want, as set quantity, select the dropdown etc. You can acess each using a findElement() in each IWebElement of the list. Example:

```
List<WebElement> productResults = browser.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'product')][not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]/div[2]/span[2]/a/../../.."));

for(WebElement element : productResults ){

    IWebElement quantityInput = element.findElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, '_qty')]"));
    string quantityValue = quantityInput.getAttribute("value"); // if you want to know the current value. YOu can also parse it in an int

    IWebElement addButton = element.findElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class, 'add-button')]"));

    // etc to all elements inside element. 
    // Remember: Element is yout complete card of the item, that contains Value, name, image, buttons and all it.
}
```

Sorry for some Java syntax error. I am not a Java developer / tester. My piece of cake is C#.

Comment: Hi Striter Alfa, Thank you for your answer. I could now get the exact result count and able to print product results without spaces using the xpath //*[contains(@id,'product')][not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]/div[2]/span[2]/a. But I don't know on how to identify the attached Qty text field, Add button of a particular product search result as the Qty text field and Add buttons have unique ids. Please help me.

Comment: @SrinivasanRamu Check if the edit's explanation helped you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me.